# Did my bike frame crack?

Tags: frames, crack

during my morning ride today, I slipped and fell down, and as a result, a crack formed on my carbon frame. I have checked the entirety of the bike and this is the only crack, but I am not sure if I would need to go repair this. My bike is Cannondale Supersix Evo Hi-Mod Ultegra.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: You fell to the right, right? I'm not a CF specialist by any means, but that doesn't look like a paint crack, more like what you see when a wooden stick breaks. I'd contact a local CF repair person to confirm that and fix the issue. Other answers are probably not going to be much different.

Comment: A crack on the chainstay means you need to get it checked out, esp. with carbon fiber.

Comment: +1 Nice picture, but it would help a lot if you could get a better one (more zoomed in)

Comment: Send for inspection to see whether a fix is possible. The crack might expand if you keep using it.

Comment: Off topic, but that's a really clean cassette and chain…

Comment: Come up with a better story and get in touch with someone about the warranty.

Comment: @onetonwonton So this is 18 months old.  What happened?  You're totally allowed to answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly doesn't look healthy to me. I'd recommend getting that check out professionally by someone with experienced in carbon frame repair. Better that than it snap later on you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the replies everyone! Sorry it took so long to respond; I don’t use this site much. Regarding my bike, I was a student in Japan at the time of the incident and the captain of my bike club referred me to a small bike shop that had helped him repair his own bike. I took it to that shop (the name is Amanda) and dropped off my bike on a Thursday. I was able to retrieve my bike on Sunday and paid 20,000 yen (approximately $200 at the time). To this day I’ve experienced no issues with my bike!

Comment: Welcome Back! Our goal as a Q/A site (rather than an typical forum) is to have detailed and relevant answers to fairly specific questions. Your answer has been flagged as "Not an Answer" because it is a "Thanks everybody" post. The way we show thanks is by upvoting good answers and by marking an answer as correct when you are the original poster of the question. Answers like this will often be deleted or converted to comments. Please see the [Tour] for an overview of how this and other Stack Exchange sites work.

Comment: You also don't say whether it was cracked or not. You could edit your question to say something like "EDIT: It was cracked, and I had it repaired at a professional shop." And you should mark one of the answers as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Gary.Ray Surely it be better to edit the _answer_ to include the answer ("it was/wasn't cracked") rather than putting it in the question? That way, this would be an actual answer.

Comment: Was it cracked or not ?

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, get it checked out.

*A good motto for life in general really!*